# Regexpression asp.net validator for a few words

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

I'm trying to create a validator for a string, that may contain 1-N words, which a separated with 1 whitespace (spaces only between words). I'm a newbie in a regex, so I feel a bit confused, cause my expression seem to be correct:

```
^[[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}]{0,}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

What am I doing wrong here? (it accepts only 2 words .. but I want it to accept 1+ words)
Any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: is this classic ASP? or ASP.Net? (Please revise your question and tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As often happens with someone beginning a new programming language or syntax, you're close, but not quite! The `^` and `$` anchors are being used correctly, and the character classes `[a-zA-Z]` will match only letters (sounds right to me), but your repetition is a little off, and your grouping is not what you think it is - which is your primary problem.

```
^[[a-zA-Z]+\s{1}]{0,}[a-zA-Z]+$
 ^           ^^^^^^^^ 
 a           bbbacccc
```

It only matches two words because you effectively don't have any group repetition; this is because you don't really have any groups - only character classes. The simplest fix is to change the first `[` and its matching end brace (marked by `a`'s in the listing above) to parentheses:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\s{1}){0,}[a-zA-Z]+$
```

This single change will make it work the way you expect! However, there a few recommendations and considerations I'd like to make.

First, for readability and code maintenance, use the single character repetition operators instead of repetition braces wherever possible. `*` repeats zero or more times, `+` repeats one or more times, and `?` repeats 0 or one times (AKA *optional*). Your repetition curly braces are syntactically correct, and do what you intend them to, but one (marked by `b`'s above) should be removed because it is redundant, and the other (marked by `c`'s above) should be shortened to an asterisk `*`, as they have exactly the same meaning:

```
^([a-zA-Z]+\s)*[a-zA-z]+$
```

Second, I would recommend considering (depending upon your application requirements) the `\w` shorthand character class instead of the `[a-zA-Z]` character class, with the following considerations:

- it matches both upper and lowercase letters
- it does match more than letters (it matches digits 0-9 and the underscore as well)
- it can often be configured to match non-English (unicode) letters for multi-lingual input

If any of these are unnecessary or undesirable, then you're on the right track!

On a side note, the character combination `\b` is a word-boundary assertion and is not needed for your case, as you will already begin and end where there are letters and letters only!

As for learning more about regular expressions, I would recommend [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info), which has a wealth of info about regexes and the inner workings and quirks of the various implementations. I also use a tool called RegexBuddy to test and debug expressions.

Comment: Wow! That's more than awesome explanation :) Thanks a lot! Now these expressions seem a bit less confusing. In my regexp, I specified [a-zA-Z] - cause I need only letters. E.g., like a regexp for a book title. And yes, I was using this site to learn, but as testing tool I used http://www.regexplanet.com. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Many book titles have numbers in them and many even punctuation in them, especially much older books - you might take that into consideration with your validation :)

Comment: For online testing, you might also look at [the tester at RegexLib.com](http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx) - it supports .Net, Silverlight, and JavaScript (based on your browser) testing.

Comment: About books .. seems like it was a wrong example, my title wont contain a letters and punctuation :)